# SAS sftp sends file with LF delimiter instead of CRLF

Tags: sas

I am completely new to SAS programming hence pardon if the question is very basic. I am trying to send a file using SAS sftp from Linux to windows server. I am able to transfer the file but the destination file has a row delimiter LF whereas our job is expecting the file to have CRLF delimiter. I tried using the termstr option but it fails with error "invalid option termstr". Below is my code

```
filename out-file sftp 'file.txt' cd='/project/dir' 
         host='hostname' recfm=v
         user=user1;
data _null_;
   file out-file TERMSTR=crlf;
   do i=1 to i=10;
      put i=;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: You cannot use a fileref that has a hyphen in the middle of it. Only valid SAS names of 1 to 8 characters are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is using an invalid value for the fileref. You cannot use a hyphen in a SAS name.

You can use the TERMSTR= option on either the FILENAME or FILE statement to change the **end of line** characters.

I thought that SFTP always moved files as binary.  You could try changing your SFTP option to make sure it is doing that. Try removing the `recfm=v` option.

Note: Text files have end-of-line characters, not record delimiters.  If you are writing some type of proprietary binary file format you might consider the characters between rows of data a record delimiter, but it just leads to confusion if you think of the lines in text files as being separated instead of terminated.

Answer (score 1):

`TERMSTR` is an option for the `INFILE` statement, there is no corresponding option for the `FILE` statement.

Try using `PUT` with a hexadecimal string and held output (`@`)

```
PUT I= '0d0a'x @;
```

From SAS documentation

> **[Specifying Hexadecimal Values](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=lesysoptsref&docsetTarget=n15rx1qcw4ydxmn10bgndbyh37da.htm&locale=en#n0ul2ccwsfvensn105q2u57n04x5)**
>
> Hexadecimal values for (system) option values must begin with a number (0–9) and must be followed by an X. For example, the following OPTIONS statement sets the line size to 160 using a hexadecimal number:
>
> `options linesize=0a0x;`
>
> Character assignments for hexadecimal numbers require quotation marks:
>
> `options formchar='a0'x;`

Additional reading at **[SAS Constants in Expressions](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm&locale=en)** will reveal

> **[Character Constants Expressed in Hexadecimal Notation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm&locale=en#n1l9fhsrv13jbtn1txnuvj61aefd)**
>
> SAS character constants can be expressed in hexadecimal notation. A character hexadecimal constant is a string of an even number of hexadecimal characters enclosed in single or double quotation marks, followed immediately by an X

and

> **[Numeric Constants Expressed in Hexadecimal Notation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm&locale=en#p1g5i6h0bvojqqn1a33cfbcxthzr)**
>
> A numeric constant that is expressed as a hexadecimal value starts with a numeric digit (usually 0), can be followed by more hexadecimal characters, and ends with the letter X. The constant can contain up to 16 valid hexadecimal characters (0 to 9, A to F)

Comment: The `TERMSTR=` option is supported on the `FILE` statement.